# How to override body style

Tags: css

I have body style

```
 html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
}
```

I have a line after footer

```
#footerBar {
color: #999;
margin: 0;
border-top: 10px solid #000;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
float: right;
margin: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Now I want to draw line starting from the beginning ...not after 15px

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Caution :**  The *html* element represents the root of a document. It's style can't be overridden.

It'll never work. After you set any style (margin, padding, height, width etc) of **< html >** you certainly can't override it and it is set for all DOM elements inside **< html >**. Either you have to go with it or you have to change it. It would've worked using this line of code

```
margin-left : -15px;
```

if you would just set the style of the **< body >** only rather than both **< html >** and **< body >**.

If you want to change/update it you can do that using **javaScript/Jquery**. You can never override the style of **< html >**. And neither you can go out of it's(**< html >**) scope.

```
html,body{
    padding-left : 20px;
}
```

In this case whatever you do, you are bound to leave 20px on left side as you've styled the base part which is **< html >** and which can't be overridden.

But the following case is different

```
body{
    padding-left : 20px;
}
```

In this case you can override the style inside **< body >** just putting some negative value.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try `margin-left: -15px` or similar? The box model won't allow you to override the outer padding from an element inside it, but you can certainly "break through" it with negative margins.

Alternatively -- and to be avoided if possible -- `position: absolute;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this right, **do not add your padding to the body**. You want to avoid global styles that box you in and are difficult to circumnavigate, which is why almost any professionally developed site will utilize some sort of `.container` element (or multiple such elements) to wrap the site content.

If the only thing on your site that needs to break the 15px padding is that one element, wrap everything in a container and put your padding there, then put the full width element outside of that container:

```
HTML:

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- all of your content goes here -->
  </div>

  <div>
    <!-- stuff that needs to be full width goes here -->
  </div>

</body>


CSS:

.container {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#footerBar {
  color: #999;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  float: right;
}
```

The styles you used for html and body aren't necessary, as you should be using some sort of css reset ([such as normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)) to accomplish basic stuff like `body { margin: 0 }`. I dropped a couple of other superfluous styles as well.